# Mark non-(null|undefined)able type arguments as a type error?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to type the function `throwIfMissing` in such a way that only `test1` is marked as a compiler error?

```
function throwIfMissing<T>(x: T): T {
    if (x === null || x === undefined) {
        throw new Error('Throwing because a variable was null or undefined')
    }
    return x;
}

type Foo = string

// should error:
function test1(x: Foo): Foo {
    return throwIfMissing(x);
}

// should NOT error:
function test2(x: Foo | null): Foo {
    return throwIfMissing(x);
}

function test3(x: Foo | undefined): Foo {
    return throwIfMissing(x);
}

function test4(x: Foo | null | undefined): Foo {
    return throwIfMissing(x);
}
```

"x/y problem" note: this function is a temporary crutch for upgrading a codebase's `strictNullChecks` flag to `true`. As we go through and remove the `... | null | undefined` types, we want unneccessary invocations to be a compiler error.

I've been trying things like [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#predefined-conditional-types), but no success yet.

Comment: strictNullChecks is already `true` ? because otherwise `string` already contains `undefined` and `null` and there is no way to distinguish between `string` and `string| null | undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `strictNullChecks` on, you can use a conditional type to see if the passed in `T` contains `null` or `undefined` and you can use an intersection type to make the parameter unpassable (at least not easily) to the function

```
type ErrorIfNotNUllOrUndefined<T, TMessage> = (null extends T ? T : undefined extends T ? T  : TMessage);
function throwIfMissing<T>(x: T & ErrorIfNotNUllOrUndefined<T, "Parameter can't be null don't check">):Exclude<T, null | undefined> {
    if (x === null || x === undefined) {
        throw new Error('Throwing because a variable was null or undefined')
    }
    return x as any;
}

type Foo = string
type dd = (null extends Foo | null ? {} : "Error")
// this is an error 
function test1(x: Foo): Foo {
    return throwIfMissing(x); //Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"Parameter can't be null don't check"'.
}

// all ok 
function test2(x: Foo | null): Foo {
    return throwIfMissing(x);
}

function test3(x: Foo | undefined): Foo {
    return throwIfMissing(x);
}

function test4(x: Foo | null | undefined): Foo {
    return throwIfMissing(x);
}
```

If you don't have `strictNullChecks` on there is no way to distinguish between `string` and `string | null | undefined`